# Proper fstab entry to mount a samba share on boot?

Tags: mount, fstab, smb

I am a little confused on the proper fstab entry for a samba share in Ubuntu 12.04

- I can get the drive to mount manually by using:

  ```
  sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.2/raid_drive /mnt/homeserver -o username=jon,password=password
  ```
- So I tried putting this in fstab:

  ```
  //192.168.2.2/raid_drive /mnt/homeserver cifs username=jon,password=password,iocharset=utf8,mode=0777,dir_mode=07‌​77 0 0
  ```
- Which gives me this error in syslog:

  ```
  kernel: [ 2217.925354] CIFS: Unknown mount option mode
  kernel: [ 2217.936345] CIFS VFS: default security mechanism requested.  The default security mechanism will be upgraded from ntlm to ntlmv2 in kernel release 3.3
  ```
- This [guide](http://www.justlinux.com/nhf/Filesystems/Mounting_smbfs_Shares_Permanently.html) says to use smbfs although I believe smbfs is deprecated?

What is a common fstab configuration for a samba share in Ubuntu 12.04?

**EDIT:**

Using the accepted answer below I was initially getting this error message (from `dmesg`):

```
[   45.520883] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation
[   45.520990] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
```

although it turns out this was due to network connectivity issues, and not related to improper fstab entry.

Comment: You could try using the server computer's IP address instead of its name.

Comment: That means you'll have to pass the password on the file? Is that a way to make the password secure?

Comment: You can use a .smb credentials file with only root permission as @russnash suggests below.

Comment: just tried your solution, but then i type sudo moun -a i get a error:
[mntent]: line 13 in /etc/fstab is bad this is what i have typed /etc/fstab:
//192.168.1.8/avcenter/Service\ -\ Installation /media/Service cifs credentials=.smbcredentials,uid=shareuser,gid=sharegroup 0 0 the reason for \ is that i read somewhere that if there where spaces in the folder then i should type \ to indicate that its a space.. even tried "Service - Installation"

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I've been through exactly this same issue this morning with 12.04 and here's how I got it working:

Install [cifs-utils [image: Install smbfs]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cifs-utils) (even if you already have Samba and related packages installed):

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` and add your entry:

```
//server/share /pathto/mountpoint cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,uid=shareuser,gid=sharegroup 0 0
```

Create the .smbcredentials file in your home directory:

```
username=shareuser
password=sharepassword
domain=domain_or_workgroupname
```

Make sure you secure your `~/.smbcredentials` file:

```
chmod 0600 ~/.smbcredentials
```

Finally, test the mount with:

```
sudo mount -a
```

...and you should be good to go!

Comment: I can't write to the share, even though the same user can when logging in with Windows. Is this a read only mount?

Comment: `smbfs` has been replaced with `cifs-utils`, other than that the instructions work for me too.

Comment: I ran into an error ("bad option: uid=my_username"). I got past it by removing the uid & gid options in fstab.

Comment: @reg The correct option is  `user` when the username is given (similarly `group`) since `uid` is for the numerical user id.

Comment: As an aside, the [Ubuntu wiki has a full page on mounting samba shares](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) including troubleshooting stuff.

Comment: //server/share /pathto/mountpoint cifs password=

Comment: refer to this link [https://github.com/mrnorouzi/smbmount](https://github.com/mrnorouzi/smbmount)

Comment: The reason why you should put your credentials into a file is because /etc/fstab is readable by everyone and so are your passwords in it. Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently#Mount_password_protected_network_folders

Comment: "username=domain/user" in the credentials file worked fine for smbclient, but @russnash's idea here of splitting it out to a separate line finally fixed it for me.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Excellent solution. Thank You.

Comment: How does this work if I have a server with MULTIPLE shares? For example, I have a SMB location `smb://nas6aba8c.local/) that has hundreds of folders/shares, I want them all mounted, but I obviously can't list them all.

Answer (score 5):

Your initial problem is in the option `mode`, as syslog says in the first line. What you probably meant was `file_mode`, see `man mount.cifs` for more information.

The `credential` approach mentioned by Eliah is indeed better than using `username` and `password`, but I don't think it interferes with the other options like `file_mode` or `dir_mode`.