# How to mount a Samba share at boot time?

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, boot-time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proper fstab entry to mount a samba share on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot)

How to add  samba share to fstab to ensure mounting at boot time?