# Execute "mount -t cifs -o username=xxx,password=aaa" everytime I reboot/log in?

Tags: mount, automount

How can I mount the network hdd everytime I reboot or start up my computer. It works just fine if I execute it everytime in the terminal but it's a bit tedious. Surely there's a way to automate this?

Comment: [How to mount a Samba share at boot time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187243/how-to-mount-a-samba-share-at-boot-time)

Answer (score 1):

You can auto mount a network share by creating an entry in the fstab.

1) Make sure you have cifs-utils: 
`sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

2) Edit /etc/fstab (with root privileges) `sudo vi /etc/fstab`

3) Add: `//servername/sharename  /pathto/mountpoint  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0`

4) Save /etc/fstab

*note*: for extra security use: `credentials=[credentialfile],user=[myusername]` in your fstab entry and create a credential file `~/.smbcredentials`that contains this text:

`username=[myusername]`

`password=[mypassword]`

Secure the file by using:

`chmod 0600 ~/.smbcredentials`

*note* Dont forget to restart samba or your machine to mount the share:
`/etc/init.d/samba restart`

Comment: Apparently I need sudo privileges to mount that in /home/me/pc1pool

Answer (score 0):

```
//servername/sharename /mnt/mountname cifs username=username,password=password,noperm,defaults,uid=1000,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=10 0 0
```

This would be better.

Then

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
```