# How to permanently mount a Samba share in 12.04 (gnome-shell 3.4)?

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proper fstab entry to mount a samba share on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot)

Currently I have a number of share folders that I am using as a very simple home server for media and other files.

This works for a manual mount every time - like clock work:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.121/mymusic /media/mymusic -o username=majikwah,password=Br6adigo
```

However, I have to mount these every time I reboot. Is there a way to mount permanently?  I have poked around with a few solutions found here, but I think I got in over my head in editing the `fstab`.

Any thoughts, suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: does your machine connect via wifi or ethernet?

Comment: also have you tried this? [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

Comment: add it to fstab would satisfy your needs