# Mount samba share in startup

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, fstab

I try to mount share permanently in Ubuntu 16.04. I read several [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247341/mounting-samba-share-in-using-fstab) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201573/how-to-permanently-mount-a-samba-share-in-12-04-gnome-shell-3-4) posts besides others. Nevertheless, I should run:

```
sudo mount -a
```

to have an access. I add to fstab the following line:

```
 //IP_adress/share/  /home/zlon/Storage  cifs  auto,uid=1000,username=share_username,password=share_password,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777  0  0
```

**What I am doing wrong?**

## UPDATE:

My HOME folder is not encrypted. When I try to mount to mnt, I have the same problem - only sudo may mount.

to have an access. I add to fstab the following line:

```
 //IP_adress/share/  /mnt/Storage  cifs  auto,uid=1000,username=share_username,password=share_password,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777  0  0
```

Comment: Is your HOME folder encrypted? Does it work with another mount point (say, /mnt)?

Comment: HOME is not encrypted. Another mount point I will try tomorrow (it is work PC). After sudo mount -a everything works.