# How to create a Bookmark that opens a Network shared folder

Tags: unity, nautilus

I am trying to create a bookmark that when I right click the Files icon in the Launcher and select the bookmark it will open the desire network shared folder.

Right now it only opens if I have previously opened the shared folder by going through the **Browse Network** option. What I want is to simply click the bookmark and this will open the network shared folder without the need for having it opened manually.

The shared folder is through Samba: `smb://client/stuff/`

Here is a screenshot of the Bookmark to Stuff:

[image]

It will only work if I have previously opened the shared folder by going through the **Browse Network** option in the Files app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper fstab entry to mount a samba share on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot)

Comment: Also look at http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/19/auto-mounting-a-samba-share-in-linux/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A link to a network folder will only work immediately if it is mounted automatically at startup; you need to edit fstab, create a folder to mount the network folder in and set credentials.

I am trying to find a good manual, will post it back...

OK, couldn't find it, but it is not that complicated:

1. Install [cifs-utils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cifs-utils/).
2. create a folder to mount the network share into (can be in your personal folder)
3. create the credentials file: `gksu gedit /root/.cifscredentials`, add the following:

   ```
   user=your_username
   password=your_password
   ```
4. add a line to fstab, to give you an impression, this is mine: the first section is the network share, the second is the folder you created to mount the share into

   ```
   //192.168.0.104/werkmap_documenten/documenten_Jacob /home/jacob/Netwerkmap cifs auto,iocharset=utf8,uid=jacob,gid=users,credentials=/root/.cifscredentials,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 0 0
   ```

I hope I did not forget anything, but I think not. Good luck!

Comment: Pretty logical. Will wait for the manual then. Thanks jacob.