# How to make a shortcut to a folder on a remote NAS-drive?

Tags: lubuntu, shortcuts, gigolo

I'm trying to make a shortcut (in Windows understanding !) on the desktop to a folder on a NAS-drive.

When the user 2-clicks on the icon on the desktop I want a window with the content of the folder on the NAS-drive to show up and the user should then be able to dive into more folders and/or open existing documents in these folders.

Simple and easy work during the day in the office ... and made with a few click in Windows enviroment !

Why is something SO simple SO complicated to do here ?

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 on an old ThinkPad connected to the Windows network and presented to Lubuntu by using Gigolo.

I can just as in Windows MANUALLY click through all the icons to the remote folder and open whatever document I want - so I believe the rights is OK.

None of the methods on Google using right-click is working - the item "make shortcut" is'n't in the menu !

I then tried using the XTerminal:

ln -s 'path to the folder on the NAS-drive' 'path to the desktop'

It gives me an !-icon on the desktop, yeah, but try when open it absolutely NOTHING happens !

How is this done ... and I would prefere doing it graphically like in Windows, but I have a feeling it can't be done this way ... how then ?

Comment: The way to do that is described here: http://askubuntu.com/a/429496/72216 create a folder on your desktop to mount the network folder into. If anything is unclear, please leave a comment.

Comment: Ha, ha, that link is simply way too complicated for me as a novice - I don't know what I'm doing - why has something SO simple to be done SO sophisticated ? In Windows it could be done with a few clicks !

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to mount the folder. Assuming it's a Samba (Windows) share:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir nas
sudo mount //<IP of NAS>/<sharename> nas
```

The `nas` folder will now have the contents of your share. This question has been answered more thoroughly elsewhere, so if you have any more questions or issues spend some time Googling.

Comment: In fact I DID some Googling and found a lot of methods but none of them works for me ... including your method. I'm using Gigolo to get access to the windows network not Samba