# Nautilus and smb bookmarks Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nautilus, firefox, samba, bookmarks

For some reason when I download a file using Firefox, I cannot see my samba sites, even if I bookmarked them. I can see the bookmarked folders, except for the ones smb:. This is what I see whenever I download a file

[image]

As you can see both "Raúl" and "Linux" are bookmarked folders. But there should also be a third one for my NAS.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see an example:<br>
http://askubuntu.com/questions/429493/how-to-create-a-bookmark-that-opens-a-network-shared-folder

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Firefox 46.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. It's been reported on Launchpad [Bug 1579543](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1579543)