# How hold smb in Personal folder?

Tags: 14.04, smb

When I turn on my Ubuntu 14 I have always search my smb.

But I use every day, How can I hold smb in Personal folder?

See the pics below

[image: See here]
[image: See here]
[image: See here]

Comment: what do you mean by fasten ?

Comment: How can I hold..

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/157140/9701

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to have your network shares mounted at boot time, you have to edit your /etc/fstab file. Go to a terminal and type

```
 sudo apt-get install cifs-utils  
 mkdir ~/DirectoryNameInYourLocalFolderToMountTo    
 sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add one of the following lines to the end of the file... (change servername/sharename,etc..)

If not password protected..

```
//servername/sharename  /home/Pasta\ personal/DirectoryNameInYourLocalFolderToMountTo     cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

If password protected..

```
//servername/sharename  /home/Pasta\ personal/DirectoryNameInYourLocalFolderToMountTo     cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

When you are finished, hit Control-O (the letter) then Enter to save. Then Control-X to exit

Now you can either reboot, or remount your filesystems from the command prompt with `sudo mount -a`

[MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)