# How to access a Windows share via Linux?

Tags: automount, shared-folders, cifs, smb

I've a windows shared folder which I can access by typing `\\share\files\` in "run".

I need to use that in Ubuntu. So I added `\\share\files\ /mnt/share/ cifs  guest,uid=0,iocharset=utf8  0  0` in `/etc/fstab`.
And then issued `mount -a`. I got directory not resolvable error `mount error: could not resolve address for share: Unknown error`.

I'm pretty new here, can you please help me?

**Edit 1:** 
I tried adding `//share/files/ /mnt/share/ cifs  guest,uid=0,iocharset=utf8  0  0` in `/etc/fstab`and issuing `mount -a` command and got same error.

I used `id -u` and got 0, used that in `uid=0`.

**Edit 2**

I used IP (`//192.168.1.222/files/ /mnt/share/ cifs  guest,uid=0,iocharset=utf8  0  0`) instead of directory path and got the following error message

```
Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: I think that should be all forward slashes? See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba#Add_Share_to_.2Fetc.2Ffstab

Comment: Related (but probably not really a duplicate): [Proper fstab entry to mount a samba share on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot)

Comment: I just tried using forward slashes with same error. Any other idea?

Comment: Then edit you question so that it is clear what you tried!!

Comment: Have you checked (using `ping` perhaps) that you can resolve share from that PC?

Comment: Yes, I could ping the IP.

Comment: You can ping the IP, but can you ping by name? In other words, can your machine resolve the name `share` to the corresponding IP address?

Comment: it looks like a password is required (no guest allowed), is that true? did you ever enter a (remembered) password in windows. In that case you need to have a credentials file let me know. Is it a NAS?

Comment: No, using any windows machine, I can access without using any password. Not sure if that's because of using same workgroup.

Comment: wait, I see you used uid=0 (root), should be 1000 (guest)

Comment: Is the `Guest` account enabled on the Windows machine? If not, then you will need to provide credentials for this to work. If the `Guest` account is not enabled and you can connect to the share from another Windows machine without supplying credentials then in that case you are (implicitly) using *pass-through authentication*.

Comment: did the uid=1000 change anything?

Comment: Can you connect to the share from the Ubuntu system by using `smbclient`? Might be easier to troubleshoot that way first before you try to mount.

Comment: Actually guest account wasn't activated, so the issues were arisen. Thanks guys for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mount a share via fstab, you should:

- create a mount point (directory) to mount the share into. I am not sure if `/mnt/share/` exists?
- use forward slash
- add the ip address of the share before the share name in the fstab file.
- if not installed already: install cifs utils
- for a *guest account* (unprotected share), you should use `guest,uid=1000` as user id, to make the guest owner.
- to enter a password protected share, you need to set the user id to the share's user name and the reference to a credentials file (see example below)

As an example, my line in the fsatb file looks like (the `\040` is an escape for the space):

```
//192.168.0.104/werkmap_documenten/documenten\040Jacob /home/jacob/Netwerkmap cifs auto,iocharset=utf8,uid=jacob,gid=users,credentials=/root/.cifscredentials,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 0 0
```

Comment: I updated question, can you please check one more time?