# Mounting network drive fstab

Tags: mount, fstab

Running this command works and mounts the remote drive:

```
sudo mount 192.168.0.15:/nfs /media/ramtops
```

So when I put this in my **/etc/fstab** I also expected it to work but it doesn't. Why? What should I put instead?

```
//192.168.0.15/nfs /media/ramtops cifs  0  0
```

Similar question:
[Proper fstab entry to mount a samba share on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot#)

I have cifs-utils installed

Comment: Your fstab entry is missing the options column.

Comment: Also (given the share name) you might want to check whether the type really is cifs...

Comment: you are correct steeldriver my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anyone else comes across the same problem the **/etc/fstab** should look like this if you are using nfs not cifs

```
192.168.0.15:/nfs  /media/ramtops nfs defaults 0   0
```