# What is causing the "mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 16 -- ignored" error?

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

I am trying to mount 5 samba shares on my machine and I keep getting the same 5 errors:

```
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 16 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 17 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 18 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 19 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 20 -- ignored
```

Here are the lines in question from my /etc/fstab file:

```
//10.0.0.23/Documents "/home/alex/Network Shares/Documents" cifs credentials=/home/alex/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=group 0 0
"//10.0.0.23/Family Pictures" "/home/alex/Network Shares/Family Pictures" cifs credentials=/home/alex/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=group 0 0
//10.0.0.23/Scripts "/home/alex/Network Shares/Scripts" cifs credentials=/home/alex/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=group 0 0
//10.0.0.23/Shared "/home/alex/Network Shares/Shared" cifs credentials=/home/alex/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=group 0 0
//10.0.0.23/Torrents "/home/alex/Network Shares/Torrents" cifs credentials=/home/alex/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=group 0 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/157140/119531)

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1053293.html or https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Filepath_spaces on how to escape spaces. Quotes won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your spaces should be replaced with `\040` in the `fstab` so it aught to look like:

```
//10.0.0.23/Documents home/alex/Network\040Shares/Documents cifs credentials=/home/alex/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=group 0 0
//10.0.0.23/Family\040Pictures /home/alex/Network\040Shares/Family\040Pictures cifs credentials=/home/alex/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=group 0 0
//10.0.0.23/Scripts /home/alex/Network\040Shares/Scripts cifs credentials=/home/alex/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=group 0 0
//10.0.0.23/Shared /home/alex/Network\040Shares/Shared cifs credentials=/home/alex/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=group 0 0
//10.0.0.23/Torrents /home/alex/Network\040Shares/Torrents cifs credentials=/home/alex/.smbcredentials,uid=user,gid=group 0 0
```

See:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/fstab-space-in-mount-point-directory-names-846362/