# Mount two different network folders as local folders, only one will mount

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, plex

I have edited the `fstab` file to have

```
//192.168.12.14/Silver Screen /media/Movies cifs redentials=/home/chase/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
//192.168.12.14/tv /media/TV cifs credentials=/home/chase/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

the Tv one works but the first one does not, I'm not sure if it has something to do with the space, but the folder does have the space. they are on the same NAS but two different directories. I can't make them the same due to the size. I need both of the folders to show up for plex to be albe to read them.

any help is appreshated.

Comment: Spaces are used as delimeters, so "Silver Screen" is read as "Silver" and "Screen" as where to mount to, "/media/Movies" as the type of file-system, "cifs" as your options etc... ie. your params are wrong

Comment: Try replacing the space with octal escape `\040` - see for example [What is causing the “mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 16 — ignored” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954966/what-is-causing-the-mount-etc-fstab-parse-error-at-line-16-ignored-error)

Comment: \040 worked perfectly, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Silver Screen is is your problem. Try removing the space. SilverScreen and make sure the mount point server side matches it.

You could also use speech marks. "Silver Screen". Doing this will cause fstab to read the folder "Silver Screen" as one folder. Without the speech marks fstab reads two folder names Silver and Screen. Of which it will only use the first name Silver.

Personally I opt to use no spaces in file or folder names. Life made simple.