# Have to be root to access a CIFS mount within a home directory. Why is that?

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have mounted a CIFS share on my ubuntu box by adding the below line to my fstab file. The share mounts without drama however if i try access the share as myself i get a permissions error, however if i access the share are root i can go straight on in and make all the changes i want.

```
//192.168.0.60/me     /home/me/me cifs    user,dir_mode=777,uid=1000,username=me,file_mode=777,gid=1000,password=PasswordHere       0       0
```

It is my understanding that by setting the dir mode to 777 and specifying the UID and GID as 1000 (the code for 'me') it would permit the 'me' user access.

No doubt this is a pretty simple error on my behalf.

Any ideas please let me know :)

Comment: Mine works, and looks much like yours, except for the `user` in front of dir_mode. I don't know what that does.  Take a look at this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot