# cannot access NAS wd mycloudex2 ultra

Tags: samba, 22.04, nas

I have a combined home network containing various windows machines as well as a WD MycloudEX2 Ultra. I recently became interested in trying out Linux and installed Ubuntu 22.04 to learn about the OS.

I installed Samba and WSDD so to access my network. I can see the Windows machines as well as being able to access their shares. I can also see the NAS but when I try to access I get the following error message:

```
Unable to access location
Failed to get share list from server: Invalid argument.
```

The Windows machines have no problem accessing the NAS.

Anyone have any clue what argument is invalid or what to do to correct it? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Silly question, but why was Samba and WSDD installed on Ubuntu to access network shares from Windows-based machines and the WD NAS? Neither of these are required. As for the "Invalid Argument", it will be important to check your logs to see which argument is being rejected. Examine the system log (or `/var/log/syslog` if you prefer a terminal) to see why the listing is failing. Depending on the version of Samba on the Windows/NAS devices, you may need to manually specify which protocol to connect with.

Comment: are you mounting the share in fstab? What is your fstab entry to do so?  [edit] your question with further details please.

Comment: as to why I have samba and wsdd installed, it's because I am a 72 yr old newbie who wanted to see what all the fuss was about linux.  I actually haven't had to use a command line interface since college days taking intro to computer programming learning with Pascal and Emacs editor.  posts I read in forums seem to suggest that to access my windows machines I would to install Samba and wsdd so I did

Comment: as to am I mounting the shares in fstab, not really sure how to do that but I am looking for info in forums and will hopefully find that some other newbie has already ran into this issue and solved it.  Just let me say that I AM really grateful for the responses to my question....

Comment: fstab entry for mounting SAMBA shares https://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot#157140

Comment: well, after spending the better part of the last 3 days beating my head against the wall I've decided to use the obvious work-a-round. I can just use a windows machine to access files I want from the NAS and then access those files off the windows machine with the Linux machine.  Not efficient but it will get me there.  From what I understand the WD NAS uses a variety of Debian OS.  Sad state of affairs when Linux machines communicate easily with Windows but difficult to communicate with other Linux machines..So far I am not impressed!

Comment: well, after cooling down, I came to the realization that the problem was NOT linux but my own lack of knowledge so let me begin by a heartfelt apology to all you good people who were subjected to my rant,  I am so sorry for my poor attitude!  I did finally get the share to mount from the command line using  sudo mount -t smb3 -o useername=mickeyb,vers=3.0, //192/168/1/114/mickeyb32 /home/mickeyb/nas/mickeyb32  This worked but only if mounted by sudo and of course gave ownership to root  I need users to be able to add to or modify files so I am trying to work out how to use fstab

Comment: of course I meant //192.168.1.114 (typo error)  I probably have some un-necessary options in there but I was throwing every suggestion at the wall to see if something would stick.  the fstab line I am currently using is : //192.168.1.114/mickeyb32 /home/mickeyb/nas/mickeyb32 smb3 -o credentials=/home/mickeyb/.smbcredentials,-user,-rw  0 0  any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: until I added the .smbcredentials i was getting error mount.smb3 failure: lack of permissions.  I added the credentials and now get parsing error in line 13 which is this mount line